# Add Brackets to Each Element in Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do have a dataframe containing multiple rows where the first row contains parameter estimates and the row below contains the respective t-statistics.

```
Row 1: Par. Est. 1 | Par. Est. 2 | Par. Est. 3 ...
Row 2:   t-Stat 1  |   t-Stat 2  |   t-Stat 3  ...
Row 3: Par. Est. 1 | Par. Est. 2 | Par. Est. 3 ...
Row 4:   t-Stat 1  |   t-Stat 2  |   t-Stat 3  ...
```

I want to modify the rows with the t-Stats so that the values are all individually displayed in brackets, i.e. so that it looks like this:

```
Row 1: Par. Est. 1 | Par. Est. 2 | Par. Est. 3 ...
Row 2:  (t-Stat 1) |  (t-Stat 2) |  (t-Stat 3) ...
Row 3: Par. Est. 1 | Par. Est. 2 | Par. Est. 3 ...
Row 4:  (t-Stat 1) |  (t-Stat 2) |  (t-Stat 3) ...
```

I literally have no idea how to start or how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use

```
df.iloc[1::2,:] = df.iloc[1::2,:].add(')').radd('(')
```